# I want when I click Edit1 the content of paragraph 1 be copied into textarea and when I click Edit2 the content of paragraph 2 be copied too

Tags: function, jquery-selectors

```js
/*This is my jquery I am working with now*/

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.edit').click(function() {
        var content = $('.paste').html();
        $('#area').html(content);
    });
});
```

```html
<!--This is my html code am using.. I want when I click Edit 1 the content of paragraph one is copied into my textarea and when I click Edit 2 link the paragraph is copied into textarea. The code now is working such that when I click Edit 2 the content of Edit 1 is copied in both cases...-->
<div class="article">
    <p class="paste">Paragraph one </p>
    <a href="#" class="edit">Edit 1</a>
</div>
<div class="article">
    <p class="paste">Paragraph two </p>
    <a href="#" class="edit">Edit 2</a>
</div>
<textarea rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter text..." id="area"></textarea>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.article').find('.edit').on('click',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var paraContent = event.target.parentNode.childNodes[1].textContent;
        $('#area').val(content);
    });
});
```

I have managed to research deeply online and come with an answer to my question. Thanks to anyone who was willing to help me with an answer.